# Is there a .net class/namespace for browsing machines on a network

Tags: c#-4.0, system.diagnostics

I am trying to write an wpf app that allows me to browse a list of servers/computers on a network (AD or Workgroup).

In the past I have opened explorer type windows for folder or directory browsing using code such as

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Explorer.exe");
```

But in this instance I don't need the user to select a folder or file just view the names of the machines on the network.

Can anyone suggest any .net classes or namespaces that support this type of functionality? I've done some cursory reading on WMI and it looks as if the System.Management namespace may be the route to take. Can anyone provide me with some suggestions to narrow in on what methods I may want to look at from this namespace?

-Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#: you can use Gong Solutions Shell Library

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GongSolutions.Shell;
using GongSolutions.Shell.Interop;

```
public sealed class ShellNetworkComputers : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ShellItem folder = new ShellItem((Environment.SpecialFolder)CSIDL.NETWORK);
        IEnumerator<ShellItem> e = folder.GetEnumerator(SHCONTF.FOLDERS);

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            Debug.Print(e.Current.ParsingName);
            yield return e.Current.ParsingName;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions however a few questions. First using directory entry seems to be specific to AD which does not address my need to detect items on a network independent of AD. I am of course assuming this since I am currently testing on a non AD network and the snippet you provided continues to fail on the ParentEntry object since (not a valid object since it is not on AD). if this is incorrect I'd appreciate any corrections. thanks